# ORDER BY ASC with NULL last and subsequent ordering not working

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-order-by

I have a query that has 3 `ORDER BY` columns: the second `ORDER BY` has to have `NULL` values ordered last;  the third `ORDER BY` doesn't seem to work.

The first table below is what my query produces - it orders the `NULL` last as desired, but the tertiary order isn't correct (row 3 and 4 are inverted).

Status `OK` on row 3 should be ***after*** Status `LATE` on row 4 since `LATE` is ordinal before `OK`.

```sql
SELECT * FROM t
ORDER BY ORG, IIF(Earliest_Date IS NULL, 1, 0), Status;
```

```
ORG    Earliest_Date   Status
A        1/1/2019      LATE
A        2/2/2019       OK
A          NULL         OK
A          NULL        LATE
B        3/1/2019      LATE
B          NULL         OK
```

This is the desired outcome with `NULLs` ordered last and tertiary order ascending with `LATE` before `OK`:

```
Desired:
ORG    Earliest_Date   Status
A        1/1/2019      LATE
A        2/2/2019       OK
A          NULL        LATE
A          NULL         OK
B        3/1/2019      LATE
B          NULL         OK
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Other than IFF => IF typo, this code is working fine. https://paiza.io/projects/9jiiYIszWRw5jqRnyxfyaQ?locale=ja-jp

Comment: the link above goes to an editor where `MySQL` is specified, the OP is asking about ms-access

Comment: Your query is correct and gives your desired results, so the problem is somewhere else. Is there a case that `'OK'` contains spaces at the beginning? Try this: `SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY ORG, IIF(Earliest_Date IS NULL, 1, 0), trim(Status);`

Comment: @forpas... I've checked... Status always contains "OK" or "LATE" since it's a value I set.  I've verified no leading/trailing spaces.  And therefore the trim I tried did not work.

Comment: @Swaroop... I must be missing something... my IIF works and it's the correct syntax... not "IFF"...

Comment: @Gordon Linoff -  I noticed that you had edited my original post.  Most is stylistic.  Is there somewhere that I need to go to learn how you did the edits to add the tags?  I didn't see the difference on what the changes were with the tables so what do I need to do differently with those in the future?  Thanks in advance for the help so I can be a better contributor!

Comment: @Magicman200777 . . . I removed the "access" tag and replaced it with "ms-access".  If you look at the edit history, it is pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff... I do see the edit but being a noob, I'm asking how to add tags as you did... I need to see a tutorial of how to add tags, pictures, etc to be an effective post.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Access so I can't test this out myself but it sounds like all you need to do is to specify `ASC` after your tertiary `ORDER BY` criteria like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM t
ORDER BY ORG, IIF(Earliest_Date IS NULL, 1, 0), Status ASC;
```

Comment: ASC is the default.  I've also tried it explicitly and it did not work.  Still something that I'm not seeing...

Answer (score -1):

The code should be fine, probably other problem, tried the code below to test it first:

```
SELECT * FROM t
ORDER BY ORG, Status, IIF(Earliest_Date IS NULL, 1, 0)
```